# Programmatically generate array name in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

1. I call my page with `show.php?city=miami`
2. Grab the passed value with
   `$city = $get["city"];`

How do I use the passed variable in a array name?

I have a array named "employeemoami". I would like add use the variable to generate a array name.

I need to get it work like this:

```
echo $employeemiami[0][0] . " Employees";
```

Comment: No idea of what you want exactly or why, but beware that allowing automatic variable creation from untrusted sources is one of the easiest ways to get hacked.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to organize your variables like: `$employee['miami'][0][0]`? This way, you won't be prone to hacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like:

```
$city = strtolower($_GET['city']);
echo ${'employee' . $city}[0][0] . " Employees";
```

Comment: And if one of the [0][0] is a month parameter (a number) that is fine using same method?

Comment: yes.. you can call it like `${'employee' . $city}[0][$month]`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['city']) && !empty($_GET['city'])) {
          ${'employee'.$_GET['city']} = $_GET['city'];
}
```